# how to Securely storing API keys and creating intermediate backends in Azure?

Tags: azure

I want to know how to store my API key and create an intermediate backend in Azure. I tried to use a key vault to store my secret API key, and then get the secret from the client side.

But it seems like it is not safe and easy to sniff. Someone told me to create an intermediate backend, but I am not sure which service is suitable for that.
is API Management service ok for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be:

- Secure the client using Azure AD Authentication using MSAL
- Build an intermediate site that you deploy to Azure App Service. The intermediate site will check that the calls from the client are from authenticated users. It will retrieve the API key from the key vault. And then call the backend.
- Lock down the Azure Key Vault. Only your App Service is allowed to access it. Only calls coming from the Virtual network that contains your App Service is allowed to access it.
- Calls from the intermediate site to the API should use https so they cannot be sniffed (or at least not read).
- Calls from the intermediate site to the API should use a private link to ensure that the traffic does not go over the Internet.